# i want the spectrum color picker onclick of input text box, but for me its not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, color-picker

i want the spectrum color picker onclick of input text box and after selecting the color, the input text box should be updated with the color code. Thanks for the help

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Color \*\*Swatch\*\* Picker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954052/jquery-color-swatch-picker)

Comment: Try implementing this .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14000157/using-minicolors-jquery

Answer (score 2):

I have updated the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/ctkY3/3640/) for you requirement. This is what you want exactly.

**HTML**

```
<div class="basic">
     <input type='text' class="ele"/>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(".basic").spectrum({
    color: "#f00",
    move: function(color) { 
        $(".ele").val(color.toHexString());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download the js file on *http://jscolor.com/try.php*. After that add it to your project and using simple code like that to fill it anywhere you want

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jscolor/jscolor.js"></script>

  Click here: <input class="color" value="">
```

Hope you like it! ^^

Comment: thanks for your idea. But i want spectrum color picker only. But its not working in input text field

Comment: Show me the source. Ok?